# How can I use more than one mouse connected to the same computer as different input devices in Unity?

Tags: unity, mouse

How can I use more than one mouse connected to the same computer as different input devices in Unity?  I want to read the input axis of each mouse individually for local multiplayer games.

Comment: This is most likely going to be very difficult to support in a released game. However, there are solutions for it: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/multiple-mice-input-in-unity/

Comment: For any kind of complex input handling, I'd suggest to avoid Unity Input and use native input instead. I think there are some packages in the asset store that do what you're asking for, using native input.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Unity Window does not allow that.
There is a new input device system in Unity that is work in progress[[LINK]](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/12/developing-the-new-input-system-together-with-you/).
An experimental prototype beta is available but I recommend to wait for the final one [2018.3 or 2019]. As pay alternative option there is in the asset store a better alternative [LINK](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/rewired-21676). All these new tools allowed you to catch any kind of input.

Comment: This answer has always been incorrect, but I can't downvote it. Rewired officially has NEVER had this feature and (having emailed the author to check) never will.